# Cancel CloudKit Query In Progress

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

Is it possible to cancel a `CloudKit` query operation that is currently in progress, and incomplete?  For example, lets say I have an app where the user enters in an email address, and then taps a search button.  The app would then proceed to search through numerous stored email addresses inside a `CKDatabase`.  If the app were to present a `UIView` that informed the user something like "Currently searching for (insert email address)", and also had a Cancel button in case the query took too long. Is there a way I could have the user tap that cancel button, and then execute some code to cancel the query that `CloudKit` is currently performing?

The reason I ask is that I have a similar situation with my iOS app that I'm currently developing.  Normally everything works fine and really fast, but there have been instances where I either realized immediately that I typed the wrong email address and needed to cancel, or when I've done tests using my cell network on my iPhone, the query can take a lot longer than on wifi.

I would assume there must be a way to do this, right?  Anybody that could provide an answer, or point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using a `CKQueryOperation`, you can call `cancel` on the operation as long as you have a reference to it.

You should then properly deal with the resulting `CKErrorOperationCancelled` error in the completion block.

Comment: Is that also the same with say, the `CKFetchRecordsOperation`? Pretend I have something similar to: `let fetch = CKFetchRecordsOperation(recordIDs: references)` that is referenced in a `UIViewController`, and then when a user requests to cancel, I could just go `self.fetch.cancel()`?  And thank you for your quick response!

Comment: Yes. The ability to cancel an operation comes from `NSOperation` which all of the CloudKit operations extend.

Comment: Perfect! I just tested it out, and it works great. Thank you!